# Lagrange Method to complete the square

Tags: linear-algebra, completing-the-square

I'm having a really hard time solving this equation:
$q(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=4x_1x_4 + 2x_2x_3$
I tried many different approaches and got to
$(4x_1^2+4x_1x_4+x_4^2-4x_1^2-x_4^2)+2x_2x_3= (2x_1+x_4)^2-4x_1^2-x_4^2+2x_2x_3$
After that if I try and complete $2x_2x_3$ to a square, I get stuck with too many monomials around.
I would really appreciate the help.

PS this is not some homework that I can't figure out, I'm trying to get ready for linear algebra 2 course, I try to study by myself before the semester starts.

Comment: Are you trying to change variable to turn the form into a sum of squares? If so, then you can do $x_1=y_1+y_2,x_4=y_1-y_2,x_2=y_3+y_4,x_3=y_3-y_4$. This gives you $q(y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4)=4y_1^2-4y_2^2+2y_3^2-2y_4^2$.

Comment: @flan If I understood you, yes, I need later to use the new coordinates to find a new base in which $q$ can be represented as diagonal matrix

Comment: @flan Can you please explain how did you figure out the new coordinates? It is not clear to me.

Comment: It It is part of the algorithm. When you have the term $ax_1^2$ you take it and all other terms $2a_2x_1x_2+2a_3x_1x_3+...+2a_nx_1x_n=2x_1(a_2x_2+...+a_nx_n)$ and complete the square. When there is no term $ax_1^2$, and there is $2a_{12}x_1x_2$ and no term $a_2x_2^2$. Then you can make the change of variable $x_1=y_1+y_2,x_2=y_1-y_2$ to make the term $y_1^2$ appear, in which case you go back to the beginning of the algorithm. ...

Comment: ... In your problem we have the terms $4x_1x_4$, no terms $ax_1^2$ or $bx_4^2$, so, we do the change of variable prescribed. After it the new $y_1^2,y_2^2$ are already completed squares. We do then the same with the term $2x_2x_3$.

Comment: See [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Lagrange_method), Case $2$, which is the case in your problem.

Comment: @flan Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not feeling clever, see the algorithm at 
[reference for linear algebra books that teach reverse Hermite method for symmetric matrices](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr)

When all off-diagonal coefficients are even, we may define $H$ to be **HALF the Hessian matrix**

The proposed matrix identity says
$$\color{magenta}{ (x_1 + x_4)^2 - (x_1 - x_4)^2 + \frac{1}{2}(x_2+x_3)^2 - \frac{1}{2}(x_2-x_3)^2}$$

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
4 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
4 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

.....

Here is the whole sequence:

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  D_0 = H  $$
$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = Q_j P_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
4 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
4 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  - 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
4 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
4 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{5} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{5} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{5} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{5} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
4 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
4 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
4 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Comment: This is grate but this specific question was needed to be tackled with lagrange,
otherwise your solution is just great! thanks!!!